# Why doesn't the general rule apply to this sentence and a plural noun and plural verb is used instead of singular noun and verb?

Tags: questions, nouns, distributives

In this sentence,

> Which of **those** would you like?

Here is what I understand that words like ''which" and "none" are singular and can be plural. The word "which" is a relative pronoun that is plural because the demonstrative pronoun **those** is plural.

However, I think the noun "you" is singular and the verb "like" is singular and "would" is a helping verb that is past tense (neither singular or plural and "you" is singular).

The general rule is that if you use a singular noun you must use a singular verb and if you use a plural noun, you must you a plural verb.

My main question is:

**Why doesn't the general rule apply to the sentence above and a plural noun as well as a plural verb is used instead of a singular noun and verb?**

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking.  What do you mean by "plural/singular verb"? Can you include the version of the sentence you would expect to see?  Is it something like "Which of those would you all likes"?

Comment: Your question and posting is simply unintelligible.

Answer (score 3):

> The general rule is that if you use a singular noun you must use a singular verb and if you use a plural noun, you must you a plural verb.

No. This is wrong.

The verb agrees with the subject.

The verb is "would"

So we look at the verb table for would

I would
You would
It would
We would
You would
They would

(Past tense verbs are easy!)

The subject is "you"  so the correct grammar is "You would"

In this question the verb is inverted, so it becomes

> ...would you like

Answer (score 2):

*Those* is plural, but *Which of those* is a selection from *those*, and could be singular or plural - more often singular, I think.

*Like* is neither singular nor plural: as it is governed by a modal (*would*) it is the base form of the verb.

*You* is a pronoun which can be singular or plural. Here it is probably singular, but not necessarily - depends on how many people you're addressing.

Whether *which of those* is singular or plural, it is the **object** of the verb *like* (or the verb phrase *would like*), and verbs do not agree with their objects in English (or most European languages) but only with their subject.